# How to use exec or execv to run find command

Tags: c, linux, unix

I was using `find . -name "file.txt" | tee -a file_path<.txt>` to search for "file.txt" recursively starting on the current folder. The `tee` command was to save all the paths to the directories in which the "file.txt" was found. It worked  just fine, but now I want to implement this command in C code.
Can you give me some help on how to implement it with `system()`, `exec()`, `execv()`, or any other function that you think is better or more approriate?

My point was to search for a file (file1.txt) and save all the paths that lead to it, in another file (file2.txt). Then:

```
open first file -> add/copy text -> close file -> 
open second file -> add/copy text...
```

I know how to use: `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread`, `opendir`, but I cant manage to get the file paths, through the C code.

Comment: You should use `readdir`, or a `sh` script in case you want to use `find`.

Comment: If you insist on using `find` you need `popen` then, but please show your progress, I can't write it from scratch for you.

Comment: I tried this `execl("/usr/bin", "/usr/bin", "find", "." , "-name", "machineparameters.txt", "|", "tee", "-a", "filepaths");` It compiled w/o errors or warnings but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to run any process for that. You should probably use the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) function instead (it would be slightly faster, and don't need any external command like `find`) to search for `*.txt` file in a file tree.

If you want to scan only one directory (not subdirectories) you could simply use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (don't forget the `closedir`); you'll probably need to use something like [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)) to build the path.

BTW, there is also [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) & [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) (& [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) & [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) ...) which might be relevant.

If you have some `char* str;` containing a path (e.g. indirectly given thru `nftw`), you might test that it is ending with `.txt` with

```
int slen = strlen(str);
if (slen>4 && !strcmp(str-slen-4, ".txt")) {
  // do something when str ends with ".txt"
}
```

If you insist on using an external `find` command consider [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) & `pclose`. Be afraid of [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if the paths are coming externally as input (imagine a naughty user entering `foo; rm -rf $HOME` as a file name).

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ....

Comment: I tried nftw and I managed to get the paths from all the files.
How can I choose which files to get the path from?

Answer (score 1):

@BasileStarynkevitch has a good answer here.

However, if you want to do what you asked, you can use the `system` call to do it, as it passes its arguments to the shell, allowing you to do redirection etc.

*Note, this is not in general a good idea because of the possibility of code injection, and because it's far more efficient to do it inside C using e.g. `nftw()`. However, for completeness, it's worth mentioning that it is possible*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef void (*ProcessFileFunction)(const char *const);

void findFileByName(const char *const directory, const char *const filename, ProcessFileFunction process)
{
    DIR           *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char           previousDirectory[PATH_MAX];

    dir = opendir(directory);
    if (dir == NULL)
        return;

    getcwd(previousDirectory, sizeof(previousDirectory));

    chdir(directory);
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat statbuf;

        if ((strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0))
            continue;
        if (stat(entry->d_name, &statbuf) == -1)
            continue;
        if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) != 0)
            findFileByName(entry->d_name, filename, process);
        else if (strcmp(filename, entry->d_name) == 0)
            process(entry->d_name);
    }
    chdir(previousDirectory);

    closedir(dir);
}

void processExample(const char *const filename)
{
    printf("%s\n", filename);
}

int main()
{
    findFileByName(".", "file.txt", processExample);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: with this approach, when you call the `processExample` function the current working directory is the directory where the file lives, so you can use `fopen()` directly on `filename`.

Comment: You have reinvented `nftw`

Comment: I just read the manual, I didn't know about it, never had a case in which it was needed. And yes, I see your ponint. Still, I upvoted your answer because it is the right answer.

Comment: Note any solution which changes the current directory is not likely to be thread safe (e.g. if another thread requires a particular current directory or calls the same routine); you could probably use `openat` and `fdopendir`. Some error checking would be useful too particularly on the `chdir` if you don't want an infinite loop. This is why it would probably be better to use `ftw` / `nftw` etc.